# Jupyter notebook TypeError

Tags: python, jupyter-lab, anaconda3

When I run my Jupyter notebook file I get the following error below: How do i Fix this problem. I get through most of the cells when running. But cannot get past this error. Image of error below. Thanks.

[image: Typeerror]

Tried adding components such as fbprophet still does not work. I added other components to Jupyter.

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/i76732643/edit) your question and replace the images with [properly formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) text. See: [*How to ask a good question*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: And to be clear it isn't a Jupyter notebook error as in your title. And you aren't 'running your Jupyter notebook file' as you imply in the start of your post. It is a Python Type error that you are getting when you run the Python code in the Python kernel currently connected to your notebook file. It is important to understand that you can run a lot of different language kernels in your notebook. The only real clue it is Python is that you tagged the category as Python.  (Remember you shouldn't be posting images so that doesn't really count as sharing details.) It is also important to ...

Comment: <continued> to understand these distinctions so you know where to look for help yourself. Looking around at stuff about Jupyter notebook isn't going to help you in this case troubleshoot your issue because you'd have the same issue if you were running your Python code inside the Python console/interpreter or on the command line as a script.

Answer (score 0):

On truth, the error gave you the answer. You must import the class that you want to derive directly and then make the inheritance to your class that you'll do your features. example: `from holidays.country import entity`